# Django: Force a field to be unique for all model objects with the same foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose I have the following Models defined in django (not tested):

```
class CarMaker(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField("Name of car maker",
                            max_length=40)


class Car(models.Model):
   car_id = models.IntegerField("ID for this particular car")
   maker = models.ForeignKey("Maker of this car")
```

Is there a standard django way to ensure that all `Car`s with the same `maker` have a unique `car_id`, without making `car_id` unique for *all* `Car`s?

E.g. There are two car makers, "Skoda" and "Renault". There are 400 `Car`s made by Skoda, and 300 `Car`s made by Renault. I want to ensure that car_id is unique for all Skodas, and unique for all Renaults, but not necessarily unique for all `Car`s.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can use the model options `unique_together` to create this type of constraint. See the Django docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together

```
class Car(models.Model):
    car_id = models.IntegerField("ID for this particular car")
    maker = models.ForeignKey("Maker of this car")

    class Meta(object):
        unique_together = ("car_id", "maker")
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. And +10 for linking to the docs :)